# Google Places Autocomplete doesn't work on dynamically generated input elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

autocomplete works perfectly on multiple static input fields. But when i add an input field by button autocomplete doesn't work on these input fields. Maybe the problem is in closure, but I'm not sure because of my weak Javascript. Can anyone help me?

**Here is the code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8">

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
<script>
var map = null;
var marker = [];
var autocomplete = [];
var inputs = [];
var types = [];
var autocompleteOptions = {
 componentRestrictions: {country: "az"}
};
```

This function dynamically creates up to 5 input fields(I put this function in initialize method and it diidn't work either):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var count = 2;
$("#addInputField").click(function(){
    count++;
    $("#inputlar").append("<input id='pac-input" + count + "' class='controlsInput' type='text' placeholder='Enter your destination' /> <br />");
    var newInput = [];
    var newEl = document.getElementById('pac-input' + count);
    newInput[count-1] = newEl;
    setupAutocomplete(autocomplete, newInput, count-1);
    if (count === 7) {
        $("#addInputField").remove();
    }
});
```

});

This function is called from initialize method for maintaininng autocomplete on multiple inputs. Works perfectly:

```
function setupAutocomplete(autocomplete,inputs,i) {

        autocomplete[i] = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(inputs[i], autocompleteOptions);
        autocomplete[i].bindTo('bounds', map);

        google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete[i], 'place_changed', function() {
          var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
          if (marker[i] && marker[i].setMap) {
             marker[i].setMap(null);
             marker[i] = null;
          }
          marker[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map
          });  
          infowindow.close();
          marker[i].setVisible(false);
          var place = autocomplete[i].getPlace();
          if (!place.geometry) {
            return;
          }

          // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
          if (place.geometry.viewport) {
            map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
          } else {
            map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
            map.setZoom(17);  // Why 17? Because it looks good.
          }

          marker[i].setPosition(place.geometry.location);
          marker[i].setVisible(true);

          var address = '';
          if (place.address_components) {
            address = [
              (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
              (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
              (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
            ].join(' ');
          }

          infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' + address);
          infowindow.open(map, marker[i]);
        });
    }
```

And finaly initialize method:

```
 function initialize() {
      var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.4700, 50.0000),
        zoom: 10,
        zoomControl:true,
        zoomControlOptions: {
          style:google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
        },
        mapTypeControl:true,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
          style:google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU 
        }
      };
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
        mapOptions);
      types = document.getElementById('type-selector');
      map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(types);


      inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("controlsInput");
      for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {  
       setupAutocomplete(autocomplete,inputs,i);
      }
      // Sets a listener on a radio button to change the filter type on Places
      // Autocomplete.
      function setupClickListener(id, types) {
        var radioButton = document.getElementById(id);
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(radioButton, 'click', function() {
          for (var i=0 ; i<autocomplete.length; i++) {
            autocomplete[i].setTypes(types);
          }
        });
      }

      setupClickListener('changetype-all', []);
      setupClickListener('changetype-establishment', ['establishment']);
      setupClickListener('changetype-geocode', ['geocode']);
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
</head>
```

And the HTML:

```
<body>
    <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div>
                            <div id="inputlar">
                            <input id="pac-input" class="controlsInput" type="text" placeholder="Marşrutunuzu haradan başlayırsınız" /> <br />
                            <input id="pac-input2" class="controlsInput" type="text" placeholder="Haraya gedirsiniz"> <br />
                            </div>  <br />
                            <input id="addInputField" type="button" value="Yolüstü dayanacaq əlavə et" class="styled-button-10"/>

                            <div hidden="hidden" id="type-selector" class="controls">
                              <input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-all" checked="checked">
                              <label for="changetype-all">All</label>

                              <input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-establishment">
                              <label for="changetype-establishment">Establishments</label>

                              <input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-geocode">
                              <label for="changetype-geocode">Geocodes</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div id="map-canvas" style="width:540px;height:380px;"></div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net). It will be easier to diagnose issues.

Comment: Thanks. Next time I'll try

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem is that you don't call `setupAutocomplete()` after new elements are added. You have to do something like this (could be improved using jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var count = 2;
    $("#addInputField").click(function(){
        count++;
        console.log('add new input field');
        $("#inputlar").append("<input id='pac-input" + count + "' class='controlsInput' type='text' placeholder='Enter your destination' /> <br />");

        // added
        var newInput = [];
        var newEl = document.getElementById('pac-input' + count);
        newInput.push(newEl);
        setupAutocomplete(autocomplete, newInput, 0);

        if (count === 7) {
            $("#addInputField").remove();
        }
    });    
});
```

**Update:** [example at jsbin](http://jsbin.com/EBInapU/1/edit). `setupAutocomplete()` has to be changed a little, commented code left there to see difference, `idx` used instead of parameter `i`.

```
function setupAutocomplete(autocomplete, inputs, i) {

    // autocomplete[i] = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(inputs[i], autocompleteOptions);
    autocomplete.push(new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(inputs[i], autocompleteOptions));
    var idx = autocomplete.length - 1;
    //autocomplete[i].bindTo('bounds', map);
    autocomplete[idx].bindTo('bounds', map);

    //google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete[i], 'place_changed', function() {
    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete[idx], 'place_changed', function() {
    ...
```

**Note:** I didn't check what will happen when you reach 7 autocomplete inputs. Maybe you will have to do some update.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, now autocomplete works. But its marker and infowindow now overrides the other input's marker and infowindow

Comment: I have made inputs array global and used your method. Look at the changed code. But this didn't help autocomplete doesn't work

Comment: Thank you a lot. I had another approach. Both of them work. If you want look at the changes

Comment: I love you Anto <3 .. you saved my days

Answer (score 3):

I have developed script which gives Google place search input for start location, end location and as well for waypoints and it is pretty If you try for once.
Here is the code. Download it and run in any browser and Enjoy..!

[Google directions with waypoints search waypoints](https://github.com/mjrulesamrat/google_maps)