# Add google places autocomplete to newly generated inputs in list items

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

```js
var start = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    (document.getElementById('start')), {
      types: ['geocode']
    });
```

```html
<input id="start" placeholder="Where to begin?" type="text" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
```

I can get Google places autocomplete working in a text field.

I want a button to generate these fields as li's and include autocomplete for in each field. Here is an example without the autocomplete working:

```js
document.getElementById('addplace').addEventListener('click', function() {
    addplace();
  });

var j=1;
function addplace() {
  var node = document.createElement("li"); 
  node.innerHTML = "<input id='place" + j +"' placeholder='Pit stop " + j + "' onFocus='geolocate()' type='text' />";               
  document.getElementById("waypoints").appendChild(node);
  j++; 
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" id="addplace" value="Add One!">
<ul id="waypoints"></ul>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
```

So the id's of inputs generated are place1, place2, etc.

I tried adding

```
var place"+j+" = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
(document.getElementById('place"+j+"')), {
  types: ['geocode']
});
```

into the definition of addplace function but it seemed to cause all my javascript to be disabled (the map no longer showed up at all). Not sure why; I don't imagine Google would be blocking it. Maybe I'm making a syntax error or place"+j+" is not a correct way to name a variable?

Thanks for your help automatically adding places autocomplete to each generated input field.

UPDATE: I noticed this question [Google Places Autocomplete doesn't work on dynamically generated input elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553673/google-places-autocomplete-doesnt-work-on-dynamically-generated-input-elements)
and will study it to try and apply here but i notice use of ajax and other things that might be more complicated than i need in that example. i.e. they reference http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js in an answer. if i could do this without jquery that would be nice or maybe more straightforward or educational for me, since i figure my partial solution is at least close / could be correct with some tweaks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess this is what you looking for:

**1).** Add button with specific `id`. Then use any element *(here `ul` with `id = "waypoints"`)* to wrap all your Autocomplete inputs.

**2).** Then add `click event` to button which generates the Autocomplete Inputs with dynamic `id's`.

**3).** Now create a click event for all those(if any) created inputs inside the element *(here `ul`)* having `id` *(here `id = "waypoints"`)* and **create instance** of autcomplete with respect to clicked Autcomplete Input at same time.

**Snippet:**

```js
var totalAC = 0; 
$(document).on('click', "#waypoints input[type=text]",function () {
 var currentInp = $(this).attr("id");
 var placeBox = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById(currentInp));
});

$("#newAutocomplete").click(function(){
 totalAC = $("#waypoints input").length;
 totalAC = totalAC + 1;
 var codeVar = "<li><input id='place" + totalAC + "' placeholder='Where to begin?' type='text' /></li>";
 $("#waypoints").append(codeVar);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>

<button id="newAutocomplete">Add One+</button>
<ul id="waypoints">

</ul>
```

Comment: Oh ya... **JQuery**. Glad that it helped you.

Comment: though i got it working to add the fields i am having issues integrating it in my application. posted question about that in case you can help, thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36551140/newly-generated-ul-li-input-values-not-getting-pushed-into-array-not-working-w