# newly generated ul li input values not getting pushed into waypoints array / not working with google maps places autocomplete

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

I have a semi-functional trip planner here:

http://roadtripsharing.com/plan-a-road-trip-js/

Source code:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

    <style>
      #right-panel {
        font-family: 'Roboto','sans-serif';
        line-height: 30px;
        padding-left: 10px;
      }

      #right-panel select, #right-panel input {
        font-size: 15px;
      }

      #right-panel select {
        width: 100%;
      }

      #right-panel i {
        font-size: 12px;
      }
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
        float: left;
        width: 70%;
        height: 100%;
      }
      #right-panel {
        margin: 20px;
        border-width: 2px;
        width: 20%;
        float: left;
        text-align: left;
        padding-top: 20px;
      }
      #directions-panel {
        margin-top: 20px;
        background-color: #FFEE77;
        padding: 10px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>

    <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="right-panel">
    <div>
    <b>Start:</b>
    <input id="start" placeholder="Where to begin?" onFocus="geolocate()" type="text" />    
    <br>
    <b>Waypoints:</b>
    <br>
    <ul style="list-style-type:none; padding: 0; margin: 0;" id="waypoints">
</ul>
    <button id="newAutocomplete">Add One</button>


    <input type="submit" id="addplace" value="Add One!">  


    <br>
    <b>End:</b>
    <br>
    <input id="end" placeholder="Where to end?" onFocus="geolocate()" type="text" />
    <br>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Plan It!">
  </div>
  <div id="directions-panel"></div>
</div>

    <script>
      function initMap() {
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
  var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 6,
    center: {
      lat: 39.6,
      lng: -106.5
    }
  });
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

  var start = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */
    (document.getElementById('start')), {
      types: ['geocode']
    });

  var end = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */
    (document.getElementById('end')), {
      types: ['geocode']
    });

  document.getElementById('addplace').addEventListener('click', function() {
    addplace();
  });

  document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function() {
    calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
  });
}

var totalAC = 0; 
$(document).on('click', "#waypoints input[type=text]",function () {
    var currentInp = $(this).attr("id");
    var placeBox = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById(currentInp));
});

$("#newAutocomplete").click(function(){
    totalAC = $("#waypoints input").length;
    totalAC = totalAC + 1;
    var codeVar = "<li><input id='place" + totalAC + "' placeholder='Come visit!' type='text' /></li>";
    $("#waypoints").append(codeVar);
});

<!--
var j=0;
function addplace () {
  var node = document.createElement("li");                 // Create a <li> node
  var textnode = document.createTextNode("<b>Waypoint</b>");         // Create a text node
  node.appendChild(textnode);                              // Append the text to <li>
  document.getElementById("waypoints").appendChild(node);
}  
-->

function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
  var waypts = [];
  var checkboxArray = document.getElementById('waypoints');
  for (var i = 0; i < checkboxArray.length; i++) {
      waypts.push({
        location: checkboxArray[i].value,
        stopover: true
      });

  }

  directionsService.route({
    origin: document.getElementById('start').value,
    destination: document.getElementById('end').value,
    waypoints: waypts,
    optimizeWaypoints: true,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
  }, function(response, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      var route = response.routes[0];
      var summaryPanel = document.getElementById('directions-panel');
      summaryPanel.innerHTML = '';
      // For each route, display summary information.
      for (var i = 0; i < route.legs.length; i++) {
        var routeSegment = i + 1;
        summaryPanel.innerHTML += '<b>Route Segment: ' + routeSegment +
          '</b><br>';
        summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].start_address + ' to ';
        summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].end_address + '<br>';
        summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].distance.text + '<br><br>';
      }
    } else {
      window.alert('Error! Do your dots connect?');
    }
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The first "Add One" button is a button and the second one is an input. I was using the input to add list items but the autocomplete didn't work and i got the advice in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36538188/add-google-places-autocomplete-to-newly-generated-inputs-in-list-items) to add the jQuery you see working for the button click.

When I comment out the "Add One!" input the "Plan It!" input stops working. If you know why that would be, thank you in advance.

My main issue is that the trip planner is not taking the waypoints and including them in the route. The code should be taking each item from #waypoints and pushing it into waypts array to allow Google to do the routing. But only start and end points are included when user submits the "Plan It!" input. How to make the waypoints be included in the route?

If there is a way to add the list items with an input rather than a button for consistency with my other inputs and a way to do it without jquery that would be great as i am learning javascript and finding jquery a little confusing though it seems to be working other than not populating #waypoints with items in a way that can be pushed to waypts. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are few changes you need to make in your JS, I already did for you-

```
var waypts = [];  
function addplace() {
    var inps = $('#waypoints input[type=text]');
    for (var i = 1; i <= inps.length; i++) {
        var a = $('#waypoints input[type=text]#place'+i);
        waypts.push({
          location: a.val(),
          stopover: true
        });
    }
}
```

check this-
http://codepen.io/himanshuapril1/pen/RaQLgv

Comment: Thanks Himanshu, in the example you linked to it seems to only show the start and end points when user submits the "Plan It!" input. How to make the waypoints also get displayed as part of the route?

Comment: Don't forget to upvote the ans if suits your need, since it might be helpful for others also.!

Comment: it it the same link? http://codepen.io/himanshuapril1/pen/RaQLgv appears to be still only showing one route segment. if users add in a waypoint "Plan It!" submission should display info and markers for each route segment generated.

Comment: You were already using to 2 'Add one' btns, so first z being used for adding multiple input tags, and the second one - `Add one!` btn adds the waypoints to route, I didn't got much dirty with HTML, simply fixed the issue in JS only. Try adding way points and press 2nd btn, and plan it btn.!

Comment: oh. sorry for the confusion i am looking to only have one button/input for adding waypoints. there were only two adjacent buttons in that example because someone recommended the first button along with jquery and for some reason when i comment out the second button (actually an input) the "Plan It!" button stops working. i can try to adapt what you did and come up with an answer or if you see what i mean that would be great to only have one button or input. input would be ideal because the other buttons are actually inputs.

Comment: It's ok if u want to keep those 2 different btns, instead give first a symbol of plus icon, and later you can keep a delete icon also for deleting the waypoints in between, that would give a better feel to your work.

Comment: i see that it adds waypoints to route, so yes good answer though i will need to figure out the button issue. thanks for your help.